# iText7 for .NET is 4-9 times slower than iTextSharp 5.5.9 while merging files

Tags: c#, performance, pdf, itext, itext7

I've tried using iText7 for .NET for merging documents into single one, after getting some errors I've created second application but using iTextSharp 5.5.9.

I was amazed that same functionality works 4 times faster than in newer version.

Below is my code for version 5:

```
private bool Merge5(IEnumerable<string> fileNames, string targetPdf)
{
    bool merged = true;
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(targetPdf, FileMode.Create))
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(document, stream);
        PdfReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            document.Open();
            foreach (string file in fileNames)
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(file);
                //not needed I guess
                reader.ConsolidateNamedDestinations();
                pdf.AddDocument(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            merged = false;
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pdf != null)
            {
                pdf.Close();
            }
            if (document != null)
            {
                document.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    return merged;
}
```

and code for version 7:

```
private void Merge7(List<string> src, string dest)
{
    PdfDocument pdfDocument1;

    try
    {
        pdfDocument1 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src[0]), new PdfWriter(dest));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }

    var path = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 1, max = src.Count; i < max; i++)
    {
        path = src[i];
        try
        {
            PdfDocument pdfDocument2 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(path));
            var pagesCount = pdfDocument2.GetNumberOfPages();
            pdfDocument2.CopyPagesTo(1, pagesCount, pdfDocument1);
            pdfDocument2.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
    try
    {
        pdfDocument1.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Dest: " + dest);
        Debug.WriteLine("Src: " + path);
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

My call looks like this:

```
string dest = @"E:\TEST\final.pdf";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\TEST\PDFS", "*.pdf").OrderBy(x => x).Take(1000).ToList();


Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

Merge5(files, dest);

sw.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

First test:

For 1000 PDF files (same file, but copied 1000 times, size 370 KB) I get this results:

```
                 |           1 pass |           2 pass |           3 pass |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
iText7 for .NET  | 00:00:13.4088770 | 00:00:13.5490370 | 00:00:14.2491171
iTextSharp 5.5.9 | 00:00:03.5330538 | 00:00:03.2058272 | 00:00:03.2854776
```

Second test:

For 1000 PDF files (same file, but copied 1000 times, size 606 KB) I get this results:

```
                 |           1 pass |           2 pass |           3 pass |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
iText7 for .NET  | 00:00:25.5538607 | 00:00:24.6525861 | 00:00:26.7326629
iTextSharp 5.5.9 | 00:00:06.0918370 | 00:00:05.5687955 | 00:00:06.0283861
```

What might be the reason why I get so large difference in performance?
Can I optimize my merging function so that it will be faster (fast as in version 5)?
I'd like to use version 7, but because of performance I'll probably use older version.

Comment: As far as I know, iText7 for .NET isn't a newer version of iTextSharp 5.5.9, it is a different library. Anyway, both libraries have the source code available, you could take that source code and run your tests with profiler. From top menu in Visual Studio select: Analyze -> Start Performance Analysis. Note that with profiler enabled, code will execute much slower, so try to run it 1 time first, instead of 1000 times.

Comment: @AntonKedrov sorry for misleading, in each pass I'm merging 1000 PDFs into one.

Comment: Then try merging 2-3 PDFs. Probobly it will be enough to find slow code with profiler.

Comment: I can confirm that I have experienced the same performance loss with iText7. I have been using iTextsharp since 2010 ( versions 2.x and 4.1.6) and the more features are added to the library, the slower it seems to get. Depending on the file I see performance degrading on a factor of 10 to 20. If you want highest possible performance look at version 4.1.6. https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp-LGPL/